# Set browser action contextmenu label for specific window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I have a Chrome extension that adds a browser button. The browser button has 1 custom contextmenu item, either "*Disable for DOMAIN*" or "*Re-enable for DOMAIN*". That's 2 variables depending on the active tab: enabled/disabled and its domain name.

I use `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` to track new tabs and `chrome.tabs.onActivated` to track tab switches. When either happens, I update the label according to those 2 variables. E.g. "*Re-enable for twitter.com*" or "*Disable for google.com*".

The problem occurs when you have more than 1 window:

1. Open new tab in window 1. Label is now "*Disable for foo.com*"
2. Open link in that tab in new window (2). Window 2's label is now "*Disable for bar.com*".

   - BUT window 1's label has changed to that too!
3. Switch back to window 1 (still on foo.com) (this doesn't trigger ANY tab event). Label is "*Disable for bar.com*" < WRONG

Another scenario is opening devtools, which changes all `DOMAIN` to `devtools` in all labels in all windows.

**How do I differentiate between windows?** There is 1 browser action PER window, but there's only 1 contextmenu label to change (which changes them all). There's no way too know which window is active/which window's browseraction I'm clicking. There's no tab event for switching windows, so I can't change the label then.

I was checking out AdBlock's code, but it has the same bug: if you open a new window where AdBlock is disabled, it removes contextmenu items on all windows and doesn't put them back until you switch tabs (`onActivated`).

Tabs events code, if it helps:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    console.log('onUpdated', tabId, info, tab);
    if ( info.status && tab.active ) {
        updateLabelStatus(tab);
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) {
    console.log('onActivated', info);
    chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, function(tab) {
        updateLabelStatus(tab);
    });
});

function updateLabelStatus(tab) {
    var host = rweb.host(tab.url);

    chrome.storage.local.get('disabled', function(items) {
        var disabled = items.disabled || {};
        updateLabel(host in disabled, host, tab.id);
    });
}

function updateLabel(disabled, host, tabId) {
    // Update label
    var newLabel = labels[ Number(disabled) ].replace('DOMAIN', host);

    // >> THIS IS WHERE I MIGHT WANT TO SPECIFY A WINDOW <<
    chrome.contextMenus.update(browserActionMenuItemId, {"title": newLabel});
}
```

Related Chromium bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=469417

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, **of course there's an API for that**: [`chrome.windows`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows). Stupid.

This baby fixed it:

```js
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    chrome.windows.get(windowId, {"populate": true}, function(window) {
        var e = chrome.runtime.lastError; // Stut up, Chrome
        if ( !window ) return;
        console.log('onFocusChanged', windowId, window);

        for ( var i=window.tabs.length-1; i>=0; i-- ) {
            var tab = window.tabs[i];
            if ( tab.active ) {
                updateLabelStatus(tab);
                break;
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Also important: in `updateLabel()` I did a few `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor` without specifying `tabId`, but without it, it'll change the bgcolor for all windows' open tabs.

Well, that was no fun debugging for 3 hours. (2.5 of which I didn't know about `chrome.windows`, damnit!)

Answer (score 0):

a simpler solution can be to pass a `tabId` when calling `browserAction`s (`setBadgeText`, `setBadgeBackgroundColor`, `setIcon`, etc), as suggested by the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeText).

[example](https://github.com/maxlath/time-capsule/commit/bedc1ec97fb661f04d606a93bc314612428481e8)